# Headers has no 'Content-Length' with 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'

Tags: python, python-requests, content-length, transfer-encoding

When I use `requests` lib in Python, there are some cases in which I cannot get `'Content-Length'` in headers with `'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'`.

Firstly I tried `requests.get(image_url)`, there is no `'Content-Length'` in headers.
Then I tried `requests.head(image_url)`, there is `'Content-Length'` in headers.

Is there any `requests`'s method to combine both of `get` and `head` method? I mean if `get` method does not work, then try `head` method.

Comment: it is called `if/else`. OR use always `head` if you need only `'Content-Length'`

Comment: HTTP says that chunked shouldn’t have a content-length header, so why don’t you simply always do a head, then you know the content length.

Comment: Because in some cases, `head` method does not work, while the `get` method work.

Comment: then simply use `if/else`

Comment: @furas I have already use `if/else` but I just wonder is there any method. Moreover, if there is any server decides to hide the `Content-Length`, how do I get it?